# How to override CSS of module via LESS?

Tags: magento2, css, less

I want to modify all css files in path:

**app/code/Aheadworks/Autorelated/view/frontend/web/css**
[image: Path to files]

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add in your theme `app/design/fronted/PackageTheme/YourTheme/Aheadworks/Autorelated/web/css`, and copy the CSS file from `app/code/Aheadworks/Autorelated/view/frontend/web/css`, and there you can change it.

For edit in LESS file, you must add `_module.less` file in this path `app/code/Aheadworks/Autorelated/view/frontend/web/css/source` and you can copy the CSS content from CSS files in `_module.less` and you can edit.
After that you must run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Thank you, I know this way. But I asked how to modify css via LESS? Example I have file app/code/Aheadworks/Autorelated/view/frontend/web/css/category.css and I want to override  this file using LESS.

Comment: I filled out the answer